# MATLAB - Secant method produces NaN

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I'm writing a secant method in MATLAB, which I want to iterate through exactly n times.

```
function y = secantmeth(f,xn_2,xn_1,n)

xn = (xn_2*f(xn_1) - xn_1*f(xn_2))/(f(xn_1) - f(xn_2));
k = 0;
while (k < n)
    k = k + 1;
    xn_2 = xn_1;
    xn_1 = xn;
    xn = (xn_2*f(xn_1) - xn_1*f(xn_2))/(f(xn_1) - f(xn_2));
end
y = xn;
end
```

I believe the method works for small values of n, but even something like n = 9 produces NaN. My guess is that the quantity f(xn_1) - f(xn_2) is approximately zero, which causes this error. How can I prevent this?

**Examples:**

> **Input 1**
>
> eqn = @(x)(x^2 + x -9)
>
> secantmeth(eqn,2,3,5)
>
> **Input 2**
>
> eqn = @(x)(x^2 + x - 9)
>
> secantmeth(eqn, 2, 3, 9)
>
> **Output 1**
>
> 2.7321
>
> **Output 2**
>
> NaN

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you give us an example input you use to this function? I mean `f, xn_2, xn_1, n`

Comment: In Newtons method this problem also exists. The common way of solving it is before computing the update on `xn`, you check the divisor. If its close to zero, you use a different method, such as bisection, and keep going.

Comment: I have updated the original post with examples.

Comment: Use the formula with the inverse slope, `xn = xn_1 - fn_1*(xn_1-xn_2)/(fn_1-fn_2)`, somewhere it is proven that it is more numerically stable than the symmetric midpoint formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `xn` will be `NaN` when `xn_2` and `xn_1` are exactly equal, which results in a `0/0` condition. You need to have an additional check in your while loop condition to see if `xn_1` and `x_n` are equal (or, better yet, [within some small tolerance of one another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738)), thus suggesting that the loop has converged on a solution and can't iterate any further:

```
...
while (k < n) && (xn_1 ~= xn)
  k = k + 1;
  xn_2 = xn_1;
  xn_1 = xn;
  xn = (xn_2*f(xn_1) - xn_1*f(xn_2))/(f(xn_1) - f(xn_2));
end
...
```

As [Ander mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262519/matlab-secant-method-produces-nan#comment97256639_55262519), you could then continue with a different method after your while loop if you want to try and get a more accurate approximation:

```
...
if (xn_1 == xn)  % Previous loop couldn't iterate any further
  % Try some new method
end
...
```

And again, I would suggest reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738) to understand some of the pitfalls of floating-point comparison (i.e. `==` and `~=` aren't usually the best operators to use for floating-point numbers).